Cloning an image file when pressing a button in a C# form application
I have an image box in the C# form application and I want to clone that image when I press it.I tried this code but I didn't get any results
private void pictureBox9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox yeni = new PictureBox();
    yeni.Image = pictureBox9.Image;
    yeni.Size = pictureBox9.Size;
    yeni.Location = new Point(200, 200);
    yeni.Name = "deneme.png";
    yeni.Visible = true;
    this.Controls.Add(yeni);
            
    Controls.Add(yeni); 
    yeni.Show();
}


The "Remarks" section of PictureBox Class (System.Windows.Forms) | Microsoft Learn has a "Note" which states

If you want to use the same image in multiple PictureBox controls, create a clone of the image for each PictureBox. Accessing the same image from multiple controls causes an exception to occur.

Thus, since you're trying to reuse the image from your pictureBox9 control, you should replace your yeni.Image = pictureBox9.Image; line with something like yeni.Image = (System.Drawing.Image) pictureBox9.Image.Clone();.
A second issue is that you have the line this.Controls.Add(yeni); and then Controls.Add(yeni);. Since you don't have a Controls object within your method, then this.Controls and Controls point to the same object. As such, this basically repeats the same command, i.e., it tries to add the same control twice. The "Remarks" section of Control.ControlCollection.Add(Control) Method (System.Windows.Forms) | Microsoft Learn has a "Note" that says

A Control can only be assigned to one Control.ControlCollection at a time. If the Control is already a child of another control it is removed from that control before it is added to another control.

As such, it seems this extra line shouldn't really do anything but, nonetheless, I suggest you delete one of these 2 lines of code.
There are several additional things to check, if you haven't already done so. First, ensure the parent form is large enough so the point (200, 200) from the upper left corner is visible. Second, run your program in debug mode, placing a breakpoint on the first line of your pictureBox9_Click method. Then ensure this method is called when you click your pictureBox9 object, and that all of the lines execute without throwing any exceptions.

The result still hasn't changed, I applied the change you mentioned as follows.
PictureBox yeni = new PictureBox();
yeni.Image = (System.Drawing.Image)pictureBox9.Image.Clone();
yeni.Size = pictureBox9.Size;
yeni.Location = new Point(400, 400);
yeni.Name = "deneme.png";
yeni.Visible = true;
this.Controls.Add(yeni);
Controls.Add(yeni);
yeni.Show();

@ArifŞenel Thanks for letting me know. I've updated my answer to specify a second issue, i.e., with you having the line this.Controls.Add(yeni); and then Controls.Add(yeni);. As I stated, to solve that problem, you should delete one of those 2 lines of code.

The new version of the code is like this but still no result                                        private void pictureBox9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
PictureBox yeni = new PictureBox();
yeni.Image = (System.Drawing.Image)pictureBox9.Image.Clone();
yeni.Size = pictureBox9.Size;
yeni.Location = new Point(400, 400);
yeni.Name = "deneme.png";
yeni.Visible = true;
this.Controls.Add(yeni);
        yeni.Show();
        
    }


@ArifŞenel I mistakenly thought adding the same control more than once would cause problems but, as my updated answer indicates, the system will remove the control from the previous usage if you try to add it more than once. Also, I've added a few more things to check on. Please let me know if any of them provided any assistance to you.
